# Deploy silverlight control through a Java web site

Tags: java, silverlight

If you have an existing Java web site can you place silverlight controls on the pages?

Or do you need a .net web site and just link to pages with the controls from the Java web site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is a client-side technology, executed by the SL control in the browser. The server code (Java in your case) only has to generate the right HTML tag and be able to stream the .xap file when the browser requests it, bot of which are trivial, non ASP.NET-specific tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but your you should think of them as silverlight apps, not controls.  SilverLight deploys the same way flash does.